# how to get a jar build in docker maven to my local repository

Tags: maven, docker

I use a docker image of maven to build this custom Scribe, the simple OAuth Java lib

[Scribe OAuth Java lib](https://github.com/gdepourtales/scribe-java)

```
[INFO] Installing /usr/src/app/target/scribe-1.2.3.oauth.jar to /root/.m2/repository/org/scribe/scribe/1.2.3.oauth/scribe-1.2.3.oauth.jar
[INFO] Installing /usr/src/app/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/org/scribe/scribe/1.2.3.oauth/scribe-1.2.3.oauth.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO]       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.309 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-26T15:06:12+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/41M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

using this

```
docker build -t my-maven .
```

The image build creates the scribe-1.2.3.oauth.jar perfectly. But i need this jar file to build the following project

[Alfresco Share OAuth SSO Support](https://github.com/gdepourtales/share-oauth-sso)

How can i get the jar file from the first build and use it in a local repository for my next build where i again want to use a docker maven to build that project

Comment: The output says that the jar goes to your local Maven repository root/.m2/repository/org/scribe/scribe/1.2.3.oauth/scribe-1.2.3.oauth.jar If this local Maven repository is visible in your Docker, you can just add it as a dependency (in the usual Maven way)

Comment: do you mean you want to use `scribe-1.2.3.oauth.jar` as a `dependency` to another module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left the jar build process out of the docker image build.

Why?

Because a better way to do this is making the maven docker image act as a single command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v "$PWD":/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.2-jdk-7 mvn clean install
```

I've taken the above example from the maven docker image [documentation](https://store.docker.com/images/3e44be96-02cf-427e-bdbe-f108ec3be831?tab=description#run-a-single-maven-command).

The -v flag attach a local directory to docker image which act as a mount point inside the docker image.

The -w flag indicates to maven where outputs the compiled jar project.